# Splitting strings in a text file and store to separate variables in shell

Tags: file, shell

I have a text file consisting of strings as shown below. I require to take the last one, split the data and store it into separate variables for later use. I tried using `| tr -s " " "\012"` which worked but can't find a way to have the data stored in separate variables. Also, I would like to do this in shell. Any suggestions please?

Content of the text file:

```
324.0 0.4444 79
324.0 0.4445 80
324.0 0.4445 80
324.0 0.4445 80
```

...

`326.0 0.5677 84` ... This is the line of interest

Thanks!

Comment: `read var1 var2 var3 < "$lastLine"`

Answer (score 0):

You may do this

```
read var1 var2 var3 <<<"$(tail -n1 your_file_name)"
echo $var1 $var2 $var3 # testing for the desired result.
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is to split the line of interest and store in 3 different variables for later use.

Comment: @user3037872 then the solution is given in the anubhava's comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read` with `sed`:

```
# use sed to get the last line and read it into 3 variables
read -r var1 var2 var3 < <(sed '$!d' fff)

# check your variables
echo "var1=[$var1] var2=[$var2] var3=[$var3]"
```

**Output:**

```
var1=[326.0] var2=[0.5677] var3=[84]
```